# tfs showing committed changes in multiple projects

Tags: visual-studio-2012, version-control, tfs

I'm not sure why this is but, I have two tfs projects

- Project A: -> Mapped to C:\dev\project A
- Project B: -> Mapped to C:\dev\project B

When I commit changes in Project A, it shows up in the history for both A and B... Why is it showing up in both?

Comment: How are you viewing the history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Seems that I did a commit without having the solution filter on. So any projects that had changes were applied.